# Inserting XSLT nodes randomly into list

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to merge two lists so that the posts are in date order and the adverts are added at random intervals within the list.

This is as far as I've got...

INPUT XML (List 1 Blog Posts)

```
   <root>
      <page>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-01">Post 1</content>
      </page>
      <page>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-02">Post 2</content>
      </page>
      <page>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-03">Post 3</content>
      </page>
   </root>
```

INPUT XML (List 2 Adverts)

```
  <root>
      <advert>
         <content>Advert 1</content>
      </advert>
      <advert>
         <content>Advert 2</content>
      </advert>
      <advert>
         <content>Advert 3</content>
      </advert>
   </root>
```

OUTPUT XML (with random advert insertion and posts in date order)

```
   <root>
      <merged>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-03">Post 3</content>
      </merged>
      <merged>
         <content>Advert 2</content>
      </merged>
      <merged>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-02">Post 2</content>
      </merged>
      <merged>
         <content createdDate="2015-01-01">Post 1</content>
      </merged>
      <merged>
         <content>Advert 3</content>
      </merged>
      <merged>
         <content>Advert 1</content>
      </merged>
   </root>
```

The XSLT

```
    <xsl:variable name="mergedData">
       <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/descendant::cwsBlogItem [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="mergedAdverts">
            <xsl:for-each select="$adverts/descendant::cwsMediumBanner [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="numberOfAdverts" select="count(msxsl:node-set($mergedAdverts)/*)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="numberOfRecords" select="count(msxsl:node-set($mergedData)/*)"/>

    <msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="cws">
        function Random(r) { return Math.ceil(Math.random()*r); }
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)/* ">
       <xsl:sort select="@createDate" order="descending" data-type="text" />
       <xsl:sort select="cws:Random($numberOfRecords + $numberOfAdverts)" order="descending"  />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Would it be possible to show examples of the two lists you are trying to merge, and a sample of the output you expect? Thanks!

Comment: Have added example lists. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="adverts-doc" select="document('adverts.xml')" />

<xsl:variable name="count-pages" select="count(/root/page)" />

<xsl:variable name="ads">
    <xsl:for-each select="$adverts-doc/root/advert">
        <ad rand="{floor(math:random() * ($count-pages - 1))}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="content"/>
        </ad>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="page">
            <xsl:sort select="content/@createdDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
    <merged>
        <xsl:copy-of select="content"/>
    </merged>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($ads)/ad[@rand = $i - 1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ad">
    <merged>
        <xsl:copy-of select="content"/>
    </merged>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assigns a random position between 0 and count of pages - 1 to each advert. Then each page applies templates to the adverts that corresponds to its position (starting from position 0). The result is that all adverts end up somewhere between the first and the last page.

**Note**:
I have used the EXSLT `math:random()` function to generate the random numbers; you will need to use your own processor's method for that.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  Just what I needed